# Shoud a Savitsky-Golay 2d/image smoothing kernel be the same when using cross terms or not

Tags: image, matlab, smoothing

W/r to the code below: (Code is Matlab but it's really an algorithm question)

**Size** - the desired image convolution kernel size

**PolyDegree** - degree of polynomial

**crossterms** - boolean ==> whether there should be cross terms

So, if, say, PolyDegree=2 and crossterms is false, the design matrix,

**A=[1,X,X^2,Y,Y^2]**

If the crossterms is true then

**A=[1,Y,Y^2,X,XY,X^2]**

Note, if there was a cubic, there would be a lot more cross terms (e.g. X^2Y,Y^2X).  However, I've tried this for 7x7 and 5x5 filters for quadratics and cubics, and for each combination, **the smoothing SG Kernel is the same regardless of crossterms (i.e. given as true of false).**

**EDIT - Actually, for the same Size filter, it gives the same result regardless of degree.** So, for example, a Size=7 filter with PolyDegree==2 and crossterms=0 yields the same SG filter (as shown at the bottom) for PolyDegree=3 and crossterms=1?!**

**Is that right or am I screwing up?**

```
x = -(Size(2)-1)/2 :(Size(2)-1)/2; % e.g Size(2)==5==>x=-2:2
y = -(Size(1)-1)/2 :(Size(1)-1)/2;
[x,y]=meshgrid(x,y);
x=x(:);
y=y(:);

if crossterms
    A=[];
    for kx=0:PolyDegree 
        for ky=0:(PolyDegree-kx) 
            A=[A x.^kx .* y.^ky];
        end
    end 
else
    A = ones(size(x));
    for k=1:1:PolyDegree
        A=[A x.^k];
    end
    for k=1:1:PolyDegree
        A=[A y.^k];
    end  
end    
C=inv(A'*A)*A'; % == pinv(A)
h=reshape(C(:,1),Size(1),Size(2)); % h=first row should be SG smoothing kernel.
```

So, for example, regardless of crossterms, or/and even whether I specified a 2 or 3 degree polynomial, a 7x7 Size bicubic (PolyDegree==3) yields:

```
h =

   -0.0476   -0.0136    0.0068    0.0136    0.0068   -0.0136   -0.0476
   -0.0136    0.0204    0.0408    0.0476    0.0408    0.0204   -0.0136
    0.0068    0.0408    0.0612    0.0680    0.0612    0.0408    0.0068
    0.0136    0.0476    0.0680    0.0748    0.0680    0.0476    0.0136
    0.0068    0.0408    0.0612    0.0680    0.0612    0.0408    0.0068
   -0.0136    0.0204    0.0408    0.0476    0.0408    0.0204   -0.0136
   -0.0476   -0.0136    0.0068    0.0136    0.0068   -0.0136   -0.0476
```

Answer (score 0):

from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter

:

> In general, polynomials of degree (0 and 1),[note 3] (2 and 3), (4 and
>   5) etc. give the same coefficients for smoothing and even derivatives.
>   Polynomials of degree (1 and 2), (3 and 4) etc. give the same
>   coefficients for odd derivatives.

so 2 and 3 degree were the same but 4 was different but then 4 was the same as 5 given the same crossterms setting.  However, unlike for degrees 2 and 3, 4 and 5 were different when the crossterms setting was off vs on.

Still not sure about the crossterms biz being the same (i.e. generating the same filter whether crossterms is 1 of 0).  Note: 
The function **sgsdf_2da** called below corresponds to the above code (in my question).  The function has the API **sgsdf_2da(Size, PolyDegree, , crossterms)**. A Scalar Size ==> a square Size x Size filter and "crossterms", as per the above code, is true for having polynomial cross terms, false for not.

```
>> hi=sgsdf_2da(7,2,0,0)

    hi =

       -0.0476   -0.0136    0.0068    0.0136    0.0068   -0.0136   -0.0476
       -0.0136    0.0204    0.0408    0.0476    0.0408    0.0204   -0.0136
        0.0068    0.0408    0.0612    0.0680    0.0612    0.0408    0.0068
        0.0136    0.0476    0.0680    0.0748    0.0680    0.0476    0.0136
        0.0068    0.0408    0.0612    0.0680    0.0612    0.0408    0.0068
       -0.0136    0.0204    0.0408    0.0476    0.0408    0.0204   -0.0136
       -0.0476   -0.0136    0.0068    0.0136    0.0068   -0.0136   -0.0476

>> hi=sgsdf_2da(7,2,0,1)

hi =

   -0.0476   -0.0136    0.0068    0.0136    0.0068   -0.0136   -0.0476
   -0.0136    0.0204    0.0408    0.0476    0.0408    0.0204   -0.0136
    0.0068    0.0408    0.0612    0.0680    0.0612    0.0408    0.0068
    0.0136    0.0476    0.0680    0.0748    0.0680    0.0476    0.0136
    0.0068    0.0408    0.0612    0.0680    0.0612    0.0408    0.0068
   -0.0136    0.0204    0.0408    0.0476    0.0408    0.0204   -0.0136
   -0.0476   -0.0136    0.0068    0.0136    0.0068   -0.0136   -0.0476

>> hi=sgsdf_2da(7,3,0,0)

hi =

   -0.0476   -0.0136    0.0068    0.0136    0.0068   -0.0136   -0.0476
   -0.0136    0.0204    0.0408    0.0476    0.0408    0.0204   -0.0136
    0.0068    0.0408    0.0612    0.0680    0.0612    0.0408    0.0068
    0.0136    0.0476    0.0680    0.0748    0.0680    0.0476    0.0136
    0.0068    0.0408    0.0612    0.0680    0.0612    0.0408    0.0068
   -0.0136    0.0204    0.0408    0.0476    0.0408    0.0204   -0.0136
   -0.0476   -0.0136    0.0068    0.0136    0.0068   -0.0136   -0.0476

>> hi=sgsdf_2da(7,3,0,1)

hi =

   -0.0476   -0.0136    0.0068    0.0136    0.0068   -0.0136   -0.0476
   -0.0136    0.0204    0.0408    0.0476    0.0408    0.0204   -0.0136
    0.0068    0.0408    0.0612    0.0680    0.0612    0.0408    0.0068
    0.0136    0.0476    0.0680    0.0748    0.0680    0.0476    0.0136
    0.0068    0.0408    0.0612    0.0680    0.0612    0.0408    0.0068
   -0.0136    0.0204    0.0408    0.0476    0.0408    0.0204   -0.0136
   -0.0476   -0.0136    0.0068    0.0136    0.0068   -0.0136   -0.0476

>> hi=sgsdf_2da(7,4,0,0)

hi =

   -0.0142   -0.0359    0.0291    0.0637    0.0291   -0.0359   -0.0142
   -0.0359   -0.0575    0.0074    0.0421    0.0074   -0.0575   -0.0359
    0.0291    0.0074    0.0724    0.1070    0.0724    0.0074    0.0291
    0.0637    0.0421    0.1070    0.1416    0.1070    0.0421    0.0637
    0.0291    0.0074    0.0724    0.1070    0.0724    0.0074    0.0291
   -0.0359   -0.0575    0.0074    0.0421    0.0074   -0.0575   -0.0359
   -0.0142   -0.0359    0.0291    0.0637    0.0291   -0.0359   -0.0142

>> hi=sgsdf_2da(7,4,0,1)

hi =

    0.0425   -0.0359   -0.0049    0.0183   -0.0049   -0.0359    0.0425
   -0.0359   -0.0575    0.0074    0.0421    0.0074   -0.0575   -0.0359
   -0.0049    0.0074    0.0928    0.1342    0.0928    0.0074   -0.0049
    0.0183    0.0421    0.1342    0.1779    0.1342    0.0421    0.0183
   -0.0049    0.0074    0.0928    0.1342    0.0928    0.0074   -0.0049
   -0.0359   -0.0575    0.0074    0.0421    0.0074   -0.0575   -0.0359
    0.0425   -0.0359   -0.0049    0.0183   -0.0049   -0.0359    0.0425

>> hi=sgsdf_2da(7,5,0,0)

hi =

   -0.0142   -0.0359    0.0291    0.0637    0.0291   -0.0359   -0.0142
   -0.0359   -0.0575    0.0074    0.0421    0.0074   -0.0575   -0.0359
    0.0291    0.0074    0.0724    0.1070    0.0724    0.0074    0.0291
    0.0637    0.0421    0.1070    0.1416    0.1070    0.0421    0.0637
    0.0291    0.0074    0.0724    0.1070    0.0724    0.0074    0.0291
   -0.0359   -0.0575    0.0074    0.0421    0.0074   -0.0575   -0.0359
   -0.0142   -0.0359    0.0291    0.0637    0.0291   -0.0359   -0.0142

>> hi=sgsdf_2da(7,5,0,1)

hi =

    0.0425   -0.0359   -0.0049    0.0183   -0.0049   -0.0359    0.0425
   -0.0359   -0.0575    0.0074    0.0421    0.0074   -0.0575   -0.0359
   -0.0049    0.0074    0.0928    0.1342    0.0928    0.0074   -0.0049
    0.0183    0.0421    0.1342    0.1779    0.1342    0.0421    0.0183
   -0.0049    0.0074    0.0928    0.1342    0.0928    0.0074   -0.0049
   -0.0359   -0.0575    0.0074    0.0421    0.0074   -0.0575   -0.0359
    0.0425   -0.0359   -0.0049    0.0183   -0.0049   -0.0359    0.0425
```